# Connect two clients using AS3 ServerSocket and Socket

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, tcp, air

I'm trying to create a simple application using AIR that connects two clients to each other using sockets.

I understand that the `ServerSocket` class can be used to listen for TCP connections, and you can make TCP connection requests using the `Socket` class. Indeed a simple test app that connects to itself or another test app works fine on localhost:

Server class:

```
private var server:ServerSocket;
private var clients:Vector.<Socket> = new Vector.<Socket>;

public function create() {
    server = new ServerSocket();
    server.bind(8888);
    server.addEventListener(ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, serverConnectHandler);
    server.listen();
}

private function serverConnectHandler(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void {
    var socket:Socket = e.socket;
    clients.push(socket);
    socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
}

private function socketDataHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var socket:Socket = e.currentTarget as Socket;
    var data:Object = socket.readObject();
    trace("Data received:", data);
}

public function send(data:Object):void {
    for each(var client:Socket in clients){
        client.writeObject(data);
        client.flush();
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
private var socket:Socket;

public function create() {
    socket = new Socket();
    socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
    socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketDataHandler);
}

public function connect(address:String):void {
    socket.connect(address, 8888);
}

private function connectHandler(e:Event):void {
    trace(e);
}

private function socketDataHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var data:Object = socket.readObject();
    trace("Data received:", data);
}

public function send(data:Object):void {
    socket.writeObject(data);
    socket.flush();
}
```

The above works on a single machine if I `connect()` to address "localhost".

Where I am a little lost is how to establish an actual connection between two machines which are both connected to the internet, but are otherwise not on the same network. Since both machines are (probably) behind a router, I presume that I need the router's IP address, and the router would have to know to forward my app's desired port (8888 above) to the machine running the `ServerSocket`? Can this port forwarding be established from AIR? Can AIR collect the necessary address and port for the current machine to establish the connection?

In other words, if a machine is not directly connected to the internet (it is behind a router), and therefor does not have a public ip address, how can another machine connect to it? Obviously this can be done with the necessary public ip address of the router that the machine is connected to and router [port?] forwarding to the machine, but it's not clear to me how to set this up from AIR or even it's possible in AIR.

For example, `NetworkInfo/findInterfaces()` returns a list of LAN addresses, but not the public ip address that is show on [who.is](http://who.is).

I can use an Apache server on a public domain to share address information between the clients, but I'm hoping to let the clients establish a direct p2p connection.

Thanks!

Comment: I worked in something like this, but what you mean by : "Can AIR collect the necessary address and port for the current machine to establish the connection" ? Because when an AIR app will connect to some other app, it didn't need to know it's own machine address !

Comment: Hi. The client needs to share its own address and port for other clients. I can share this info via an HTTP server (PHP + SQLite). However, if the client is behind a router, the addresses from `NetworkInfo/findInterfaces()` does not seem to reveal the public ip address, like you see on who.is for example. So how do I get two machines behind routers to connect?

Comment: I added a bit of clarification.

Comment: For the public IP address, you need a server side service. For clients connections, I think that in all cases, you need a server. Your client connect to it, and then it can get other clients address to do connections. Of course when using a server, client don't need to know its address because server can get it.

Comment: I'm still confused. I have an Apache server, but what does the "server side service" do? I can share addresses of clients, but those addresses will only get a client as far as the router that the other client is connected to.

Comment: I don't know exactly what your clients will share, but I'll put an answer just because I can't explain more here.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly. I could make a server app in AIR and have client apps outside my network connect through it, as long as I port forward for the server? I'm only asking like this because I have no knowledge of the subject and I dont have enough reputation points to comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question's 2 years old, but for those people scratching their heads about it in the future:

I just got your code working on my end; you need to port forward on the server's computer. Basically, have your router point any incoming 8888 TCP traffic to the computer running the server (have it point to the computer's 8888 port).

The client doesn't need to have port forwarding done to it because when the server replies, the client's router sees it as a "response" and allows the packet through.

Other than that, just connect the client to the server's (router's) public IP which you can find by going [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/).

Comment: Blast from the past. :) How did you setup the server's port forwarding? Manually configuring your router, or through the AIR app itself? The thing is many p2p apps do not require you to mess with your router, and I never quite figured out how they manage to do that and if you can do the same from an AIR app.

Comment: @Aaron I had to set it on the router. While I'm no expert, I think what you're referring to probably involves UDP/TCP hole punching which is a rabbit hole I haven't gone down yet. The only reasonable solution in my experience is to forward ports on a server.

If you figure out how to get the AIR app to do it without messing with the router, let me know! But as far as I'm aware, it's really complicated to get working.

Comment: @Aaron Did my answer end up helping?